# Are there fast methods to factor a covariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I have an covariance matrix $\hat C$ (squared, symmetric, positive semidefined). I would like to approximate it by the following expression:

$
\hat C = \hat I \cdot \vec \gamma^2 + \hat \beta \cdot \hat \beta^T
$

In the above expression $\hat I$ is a unitary matrix, $\vec \gamma$ is a column vector, $\vec \beta$ is a $n$ by $k$ matrix, where $k < n$.

---

In other words, every row $i$ (and column $i$) is represented by a k-dimensional vector $\vec \beta_i$. Every off-diagonal element of matrix $\hat C$ is given by a scalar product of two corresponding vectors:

$
C_{ij} = (\vec \beta_i, \vec \beta_j) 
$

The diagonal elements of the covariance matrix are given by the following expression:

$
C_{ii} = (\vec \beta_i, \vec \beta_i) + \gamma_i^2 
$

---

So, my question is if there is a fast analytical method to calculate $\vec \gamma$ and $\hat \beta$? Or, alternatively, if an iterative method to calculate $\vec \gamma$ and $\hat \beta$?

I probably need to add, that I try to minimize the squared deviations between the original covariance matrix and the matrix that tries to approximate it.

Comment: The [Cholesky-Banachiewicz algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky%E2%80%93Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky%E2%80%93Crout_algorithms) is very fast.

Comment: But doesn't it do something different? I mean, it fast but it does not do what I need.

Comment: Cholesky calculates $C=\beta\beta^\top$ and this $\beta$ is unique. Why do you need also that $\gamma$ ? It makes the solution non unique.

Comment: It is important that my $\beta$ is not $n$ by $n$. It is $n$ by $k$, where $k < n$. This is the difference.